# ASP.NET Deployment for common Windows Users

Tags: asp.net, iis

i want to make a Windows Application in ASP.NET.

My question is :

What are the Windows requirements for it to run ?

Is IIS installed on all Windows versions from Vista and above ?

If a newbie user wants to install my ASP.NET application what is necessary for him to do ?

Is there a way to automate this process ?

Answer (score 0):

You need the following installed:

- The .NET runtime, probably .net 4.0.
- You don't need IIS to develop, but you need it to host your application

  - For development you can use IIS Express or the built in web server in Visual Studio
- You install IIS from windows features
- For automating the process there are several option depending on how advanced you want to be. Check out [octopusdeploy](http://www.octopusdeploy.com) for a release manager, but you still need to package the project as an artifact suitable for Octopus deploy. Also, check out [web deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)

Answer (score 0):

A If you want install , you can use

1 Installer Windows

2 Click Once

3 Or XCopy

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3bb4tfd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

B If you want automatize deployement, you can use `Team Foundation Server` and define BuildDefinition

Nota : You need Visual Studio in order to develop your application